# Azure Devops DownloadBuildArtifacts buildType, specificBuildWithTriggering, & buildVersionToDownload

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure pipelines. My team has inherited an existing pipeline, and I am just trying to figure out what these specific settings are doing.

We have a stage with a job with a task:

```yaml
task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
inputs:
  buildType: 'specific'
  specificBuildWithTriggering: true
  buildVersionToDownload: 'latestFromBranch'
  branchName: '<path-to-branch>'
```

There are more settings of course, but I'm really trying to wrap my head around the "buildType: specific" one. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) say "Download artifacts produced by the current build, or from a specific build." But I'm not sure how we're specifying "specific". Is it the `specificBuildWithTriggering` setting? Or is the the `buildVersionToDownload` setting?

Trying to read this (and ignoring "specific"), it looks like we're saying "build with artifacts from the triggering commit, but also get the latest". To me, those could be different, if 2 builds are triggered by rapid commits. Am I reading that right? What happens if there is a conflict?

Finally, the default for `buildType` is `'current'`. To me this sounds like, "just download the current from the branch" ... which to me also sounds like I could skip 3 of those settings, right?

Thanks for any clarity the community can provide!